# how to get the top window under mouse in mac

Tags: macos

I want to develop a screen shot tool in mac，I need to get  the top window under my  mouse.

There is  "ChildWindowFromPointEx" API in Windows OS, but Mac is more complex.

Does anybody know how to deal with it? Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

`windowNumber` returns the number of the frontmost window that would be hit by a mouse-down at the specified screen location. According to the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419210-windownumber).